# Calling actionlistener of a disabled JButton

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton, actionlistener

I was working on something in which I need to call the `actionlistner` of a disabled `jbutton` from another function. How it can be done?

Comment: the way to thank the helpers is to upvote/accept their post/s :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You cannot** call/do `actions` on `disabled` GUI controls.That is what actually `disable` means

What you can do is create a separate common method like `doClick()` and call where ever you need.

Answer (score 5):

Make a new method which will be called by the disabled jbutton, write all the code there which will be executed when you click the button. You can not call the `actionlistiner` in other way.

```
...
JButton disButton = new JButton("Disabled");
disButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    //do not write any statement here
    doSomething();
  }
});

...
private void doSomething() {
  //all action event execution code here
  System.out.println("I am in the action listener");
}

....

//in  the other method or another button click event call doSomething()
//even button is disables like
JButton Button = new JButton("Submit");
Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    doSomething();
  }
});

//or from another method
public void method() {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Actually while creating jButton i need to fixed certain parameters in it's action performed method which are not static so i simply can't call another method

Comment: fix these parameters in the called function, or pass them from the action preformed.